# Jersey with MVC Templates and Tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, model-view-controller, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to set up an simple application with Jersey 2.3 serving a jsp page in a standalone Tomcat. I've tried a lot of howto's from the web but the most of them are explaining using Jersey with Grizzly and not Tomcat. So I couldn't find a solution / explanation for my problem why the jsp is not served by my application. Does somebody has an idea what's wrong or missing here? Please find below my application.

**pom.xml**

```
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>tomcat-run</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/jhello</path>
                        <enableNaming>false</enableNaming>
                        <finalName>jhello-standalone.jar</finalName>
                        <charset>utf-8</charset>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>jhello</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.granatasoft.playground.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/views</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>/(decorators|scripts|styles|resources|(WEB-INF/views))/.*</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jhello</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**HelloJersey.java**

```
package com.granatasoft.playground.jersey;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloJersey {
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String sayJsonHello() {
    return "{'hello': 'jersey'}";
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Viewable sayHtmlHello() {
    return new Viewable("hello");
}
}
```

**hello.js**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Hello JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello JSP</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

You're using old property (`com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath`) name for base-path. Try using new one

```
jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp
```

(see properties in [JspMvcFeature](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/mvc/jsp/JspMvcFeature.html) and [MvcFeature](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/mvc/MvcFeature.html)).

The other property (`com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex`) is not supported in Jersey 2.x at the moment.

Comment: That link is dead. The new one is https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/

Comment: Thanks, fixed also in the answer.

Comment: The links changed again. I updated them in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some Jersey filter init params you might want to take a look at (I'm using Jersey 2.5 inside Tomcat 7 - the rest of my web.xml looks similar to yours):

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.tracing</param-name>
        <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>(/index.jsp)|(/(content|(WEB-INF/jsp))/.*)</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

The JspMvcFeature param might be useful in your situation.  You can also see the static content configuration as well as tracing which you should definitely find useful at some point.

Comment: I am trying to return a JSP from my ReST service, but after doing all the configuration in `web.xml`, can't get a JSP in the response. After hitting the URL, I could only see `{"templateName":"/TerstJSP","model":[],"resolvingClass":null,"templateNameAbsolute":true}` as a response.